# PostgreSQL Converting Two String Date Columns (Year,Month) to One Column (YYYY/MM/DD)

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a PostgreSQL table with a Month attribute and Year attribute. They are both formatted as Strings... that is: September, October, November, December and '2016','2017','2018'. How can I combine these month and year columns into a Date column that has the format YYYY/MM/01 indicating the first day of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1dae2fae3d0f09ac64e5c05504d38829)

**First step:** Generating a `date` with `to_date()`: Identifier `Month` detects the long month name

```
SELECT to_date(year || '-' || month || '-01', 'yyyy-Month-dd')
```

**Second step:** Generating your expected date format with `to_char()`

```
SELECT 
    to_char(
        to_date(year || '-' || month || '-01', 'yyyy-Month-dd'),
        'yyyy/MM/dd'
    )
FROM mydates
```

[Postgres date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Postgres doesn't even need the day here: `SELECT to_char(to_date(year||month, 'yyyyMonth'), 'yyyy/MM/dd') FROM mydates;`